# How long are nextPageTokens remembered for Gmail and Calendar APIs?

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api, gmail-api

The Gmail and Calendar APIs return a `nextPageToken` value in the response from the `users.messages.list` and `events.list` endpoints when pagination is required. If the value of the `nextPageToken` is provided in the next request to these endpoints, the next page of results is returned.

**My question**: How long are these `nextPageToken`s persisted behind the Gmail and Calendar APIs?

**Context**: I am building an abstraction on top of both the Gmail and Calendar APIs to return a list of Activities, and this endpoint has its own pagination. My pagination works by storing the `nextPageToken` values returned by the Gmail and Calendar APIs in a cache and returning a UUID the client can specify in the next request to pop and use those Gmail and Calendar `nextPageToken`s (just like the Google APIs themselves).

**Goal**: Configure my pagination cache TTL to, at most, be equal to the TTL (if there is one) of the Google APIs so that it always works as intended.

Comment: I don't believe they have an expiry as I believe they are just a pointer to an index. This means that if page 1 returns results 1-30 and then 10 items are added the `nextPageToken` will return results 21-50 of the original set.(31-60 of the new set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextPageToken` does not expire. It is just like an Index position. However if new items are added/deleted, you might not see the same result as you expect.

Comment: Is this officially documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The token expires after 1 Hour. I came to know about that while working with Google Directory API. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661575/nextpagetoken-gives-invalid-input-error-400-google-directory-api-chomedevices) to the problem I faced.